# What operator to overload if i want to use " a = {x, y};"

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm making my own class and i'd like to be able to initilize it like the title.

```
a = {x, y};
```

I haven't been able to find anything to point me how to do that.

Comment: Initialize it, or assign to it? Also, in what way are you going to use the elements of the list?

Comment: Have you even tried doing that? It will work.

Comment: @0x499602D2: It will work... if your compiler supports C++11-style braced initialisers, and the type is suitable for such an assignment.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` the same type?

Comment: Yes they are. A looks like this:

class a
{
int x, y;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to be able to assign in that way (not initialize), you need to overload `operator=`, but its argument types depend on exactly what the list within the braces represents.

If, for example, you are always going to be passing a pair of values, then you can have an `operator=` overload that takes a `std::pair`:

```
A& operator=(std::pair<int, int>);
```

This would be callable like so:

```
A a;
a = {5, 3};
```

If you want to be able to pass an arbitrary length list, you could have the argument type as an `std::initializer_list`:

```
A& operator=(std::initializer_list<int>);
```

Now all of the following would be fine:

```
a = {};
a = {1, 2};
a = {5, 3, 5, 2, 3};
```

Comment: I'm guessing i want to initialize it. i just SDL_Rect() like this: 
SDL_Rect rect = {x, y, w, h};

That's what i want to do but with only x and y in my own class.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, you can do that by just making a constructor using **std::initializer_list** template class as a parameter, and you can overload **operator=** in analogous way. I am not aware of any trick in C++03 or C++98 that does that, though.

Copypasta from Wikipedia:

```
class SequenceClass {
public:
    SequenceClass(std::initializer_list<int> list);
};
```